# GIT descargar ficheros modificados de un commit

Tags: git, gitlab

necesito crear un paquete con los ficheros que he modificado en un commit especifico.

```
git archive --output=latest_artifact.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD^1)
```

Ejecutando este comando me crea un fichero con el árbol de ficheros generados/modificados en el ultimo commit.

Necesito recuperar ficheros del commit X.

Si ejecuto esto para recuperar los ficheros del commit ID_COMMIT_XXXX

```
git archive --output=<nom_fichero.zip> < ID_COMMIT_XXXX > $(git diff --name-only  < ID_COMMIT_XXXX >  < ID_COMMIT_ANT >)
```

funciona, pero tengo un problema, si el commit ha subido ficheros con espacios (nombre fichero.jpg) muestra error. No encuentra ".../nombre"

¿Hay alguna forma para indicarle que también coja ficheros con espacios y acentos?

Utilizo GITLab, ¿desde ahí se podría también realizar?

Saludos

Comment: Has probado a poner el nombre de los ficheros entre comillas? `'nombre de fichero.zip'`

Comment: El problema no es el archivo de salida, sino en los archivos a incluir en el zip, @PabloLozano

Answer (score 0):

Como estas sacando los archivos de HEAD, podrias crear un archivo con zip:

```
git show --name-only --pretty="" HEAD | zip -@ blahblah.zip
```

Si es de otra revision que lo quieres sacar, haz un checkout a esa revisión y entonces usas el comando. No es elegante, pero funciona